# Redirect users after log in who have purchased a product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, redirect, woocommerce

I am building websites in Wordpress, but I don't have enough knowledge in PHP to do the following:

I am wondering if it is possible to create a code to redirect users (WooCommerce customers) after log in to a certain page and customers who have purchased a product (any product) to a different page?

Since WooCommerce (to my knowledge) doesn't distinguish user roles for customers who have purchased a product and customers who just created an account, is this possible?

I would like the customers who just logged in without purchasing the product to be redirected to page A and the customers who logged in and have already purchased the product to be redirected to page B.

My code currently looks like this but it doesn't distinguish paid from unpaid customers:

```
function ts_redirect_login( $redirect) {

$redirect_page_id = url_to_postid( $redirect );
$checkout_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
$redirection_url = ( '/page-A/' );

if( $redirect_page_id == $checkout_page_id ) {
return $redirect;
}

return $redirection_url;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ts_redirect_login' );
```

This redirects ALL the users to page A (unless they are in checkout), but doesn't split the redirect for paid and unpaid users.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved without a plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it:

```
function ts_redirect_login( $redirect) {
    if( isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) ){
        $user_data = get_user_by(is_email( $_POST['username'] ) ? 'email' : 'login', $_POST['username']);
        $user_id = $user_data->data->ID;
        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => $user_id,
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        ) );
        if($customer_orders){
            // Purchased user
            $redirect = get_permalink(37); // replace with your page link
        }else{
            // Non purchased user
            $redirect = get_permalink(271); // replace with your page link
        }
    }
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ts_redirect_login' );
```